# Algebraic dependence of polynomials in several variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $a_1,a_2 \in k[x_1,x_2]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
There is a result (that can be found in a paper of [Nagata](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/212692/1/1989-12.pdf), Corollary 1.3) saying that if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are algebraically dependent over $k$, then there exists a polynomial $h \in k[x_1,x_2]$ such that $a_1=u_1(h)$ and $a_2=u_2(h)$, where $u_1(t), u_2(t) \in k[t]$.

My question is what happens in higher dimensions, namely:

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
>   Is it true that if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are algebraically dependent over $k$, then there exist $n-1$ polynomials $h_1,\ldots,h_{n-1} \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $a_i=u_i(h_1,\ldots,h_{n-1})$, where $u_i(t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}) \in k[t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}]$,
>   $1 \leq i \leq n$.

For example, $n=3$, $a_1=a_2=xyz$, $a_3=z$, so in this case $h_1=xyz$ and $h_2=z$.

**Remarks:** (1) In $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n$ polynomials are algebraically dependent iff their Jacobian is zero.
(2) Perhaps there is a connection between my above question and the kernel conjecture?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Though  I do not have a specific example, I suspect this false. Similar question with fields ($a_i\in k(x_i)=K$, algebraically dependent does not mean you have $h_i\in K$ and $u_i\in k(t_1,\ldots, t_{n-1})$ with $a_i=u_i(h_j)$).  The field question for $n\geq 4$ is false, because there are unirational non-rational varieties of dimension $\geq 3$. For $n=3, k=\mathbb{C}$, this is true, since  unirational surfaces are indeed rational over complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps, according to your comment, my question has a positive answer in the following cases: (i) $n=2$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero (by Nagata's Corollary 1.3). (ii) $n=3$, $k=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $n=2$, you do not need characteristic zero.

Comment: Any reference? Actually, in Nagata's paper he assumes that $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic zero, not just of characteristic zero.

Comment: Any suggestions what should be the right statement (and how to prove it)? Is this known and appears in the literature?

Comment: Algebraically closed, yes, not char 0. I can't think of a right statement in general, other than what I said that can go wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comments; I liked the idea of considering $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.