# A pure algebraic proof for: Any unirational surface over $\mathbb{C}$ is rational.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (for example, $k=\mathbb{C}$).
Let $L$ be a field such that $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$ 
and $L$ is of transcendence degree two over $k$. 
Then there exist $h_1,h_2 \in k(x,y)$ such that $L=k(h_1,h_2)$.

This seems a known result in algebraic geometry, according to the comments in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287000/generalizations-of-l%C3%BCroth-theorem) (especially the last one).

Please:

> (1) Is there a pure algebraic proof for this result?
>
> (2) Is it possible to find $h_1,h_2 \in k[x,y]$? The motivation is the following result: If $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$ is of transcendence
>   degree one over $k$, then $L=k(h)$, where $h \in k[x,y]$; see the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190920/any-two-bivariate-algebraically-dependent-polynomials-are-always-in-the-same-rin/191058#191058).

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** 
**(1)** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_surface) only brings the algebraic geometry terminology. 
Also, [this notes](http://ajwilson.co.uk/files/maths/luroth-problem.pdf) talk in algebraic geometry terminology (except for the first chapter).
**(2)** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383956/algebraic-dependence-of-polynomials-in-several-variables?rq=1) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical result in algebraic geometry. It is a direct consequence of the Castelnuovo criterion of rationality.

You can find a proof of it for instance in

Beauville: " Complex algebraic surfaces" Chapter V

Or

Badescu : "Algebraic surfaces" Chapter 13

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. But I wished to see a pure algebraic proof, without using algebraic geometry.